# Xcode testplan inherit environment variables from scheme

Tags: swift, xcode

I have an `xctestplan` in a library that I'm building that contains all the tests for the library. The tests need to access sensitive data. I would like to store this data in the environment variables for a scheme, but the tests don't seem to have access to these variables when I run them using a test plan. They only have access to the environment variables defined in the configuration for the test plan.

**Is it possible for an `xctestplan` to inherit/access the environment variables from a scheme?**

The reason I want to do this is because this library is publicly available on github. I want the `xctestplan` file to be tracked by git so that users can run the unit tests themselves if they want to. This file is stored in JSON format. If I add environment variables to the test plan, then they show up in this file. Therefore, I cannot store any sensitive information in this file. The temporary solution I have implemented is a separate, untracked, copy of the test plan that contains the sensitive data in the environment variables. This is not ideal because I need to keep these copies in sync with each other.

Storing the environment variables in a scheme is a better solution because I don't need to change it whenever I make changes to the test plan. It's also simpler to exclude schemes from git by unchecking the `shared` option.

I am creating a [Spotify web API library](https://github.com/Peter-Schorn/SpotifyAPI). The sensitive information is the client id and client secret that Spotify uses for authentication requests.

With all of that said, if their is a better method of injecting sensitive data at runtime, I'm all ears.

Comment: This seems like possibly an x-y question. Could we focus on the sensitive data problem itself, and not make assumptions about how to access it? Could you describe that situation and what you ultimately want to do?

Comment: Thanks for your response, Matt. I'll additional information to the question.

Comment: Hmm. How would I do this? Suppose I had a file of info that I wanted my project to use but didn't want to end up in the public source code. I'd keep it in a different folder. The project can still reference it, I can still build it into the app when I build, but it will never end up online because it's not in the git working tree. For the public, the file will simply be missing (it will appear as red in the project navigator). They will know something is missing but they won't know the contents.